# Limit download speed of HttpClient via ReadAsStreamAsync

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have this function below that downloads a multipart file from our API.  Our files range from 5MB to 300MB.  I'd like to put in logic to calculate the download speed it currently is transferring at, if it's higher than a configurable limit, slow down the download to be at or below the limit.

I've tried sleeping the thread, but that slows it down quite a bit.  Is buffer the only configurable thing I can change or is there some other HttpClient way to do this?

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
    string.Format("/api/device/DownloadFile/?fileID={0}", fileID));

using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(request.RequestUri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result)
{
    try
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Logging.LogDebug(string.Format("[DownloadFile] Starting download of '{0}'...", fileID));
            int downBuffer = 512;
            using (System.IO.Stream contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileLocationTemp.FullName, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.None, downBuffer, true))
            {
                var totalRead = 0L;
                var totalReads = 0L;
                var buffer = new byte[downBuffer];
                var isMoreToRead = true;

                do
                {
                    var read = await contentStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (read == 0)
                    {
                        isMoreToRead = false;
                    } else
                    {
                        await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);

                        totalRead += read;
                        totalReads += 1;

                        if (totalReads % 2000 == 0)
                        {
                            Logging.LogDebug(string.Format("[DownloadFile] Total bytes downloaded so far: {0:n0}", totalRead));
                        }
                        
                        //I tested putting this in to slow it down.  It definitely slowed it down, but too much
                        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
                    }
                }
                while (isMoreToRead);
            }

        } else if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            Logging.LogDebug(string.Format("[DownloadFile] Failed to download file '{0}', not found on server.", fileID));
            deleteFilesOnFinal = true;
            return false;
        } else
        {
            Logging.LogDebug(string.Format("[DownloadFile] Failed to download file '{0}', status code '{1}'.", fileID, response.StatusCode.ToString()));
            deleteFilesOnFinal = true;
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logging.LogDebug(string.Format("[DownloadFile] Failed to download file '{0}'", fileID));
        Logging.LogError(ex);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: How about using a [Task.Delay(n)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-5.0) - where n is milliseconds of delay - instead of Thread.Sleep?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I will try this and report back.